# Installer for Software? Paas?

Tags: rest, architecture, cloud, saas, paas

currently I'm looking for an open source project that gives me the opportunity to install software easily. I prefer direct calls or access with a REST interface.

I thought that CloudFoundry would fits my needs but it is'nt so. 
AppFog (https://www.appfog.com/product/) comes much closer to my goal. It allows me to install Drupal, Wordpress, PhpMyAdmin, NodeJS Apps and so on.

The conclusion is that I'm looking for an project that...

- is open source.
- gives that possibility to install, configure and
  uninstall software
- is extendable when a specific software not
  available
- is accessible with an interface like REST.
- is "hostable" on my own linux server

I would be happy for all kind of hints and tips :)

Cheers Tobias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docker](http://docker.com) is seems to be the next big thing in the PaaS world. There are dozens new projects that build on top of docker or supporting it. For example OpenShift and Apache Stratos support docker. So if you look at solutions based on docker you can find a solution for you needs. 
Right now I'm using docker for hosting couple of Drupal websites with simple bash scripts to manage them. Nginx is used for web traffic routing

1. Docker is open source
2. Gives you ability to prepare and install apps
3. You can build what you need on top of it
4. It has REST interface
5. It is running on nearly all major Linux distros
6. Its relatively easy to learn and use
7. Has great community

Answer (score 3):

Tobias,

Suggest you look at **Apache Stratos:**

- 100% open source
- Easy to Get Up and Running
- Highly extensible, flexible, expandable
- Uses REST APIs
- Runs on Linux (Ubuntu or SUSE)
- Mature (version 4)

See:

- **Intro article -- "Why Apache Stratos is the Preferred Choice in the PaaS Space"**
  http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/05/why-apache-stratos-is-the-preferred-choice-in-the-paas-space/
- **Apache Stratos Project site** -- which notes that "Stratos PaaS is easy to get it up and running in quick time. A developer will be able to run and test PaaS framework on a single machine to try out."
  http://stratos.apache.org/

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll have a look

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift is what you looking for :

1. it is open source and free for 3 gears for ever.
2. gives that possibility to install, configure and uninstall software in [openshift.redhat.com](https://www.openshift.com/) or in [rhc client tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install).
3. it is extendable when a specific software not available is accessible throw [DIY(Do it yourself)](https://www.openshift.com/developers/do-it-yourself)
4. with an [REST interface](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/REST_API_Guide/)
5. is "hostable" on [Fedora or CentOS](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html) .
6. It is really easy to setup throw Eclipse.

Comment: try to visit  [Arun Gupta page](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/04/25/Getting-Started-WildFly-OpenShift) for more details